# Persistent set is empty with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with a few fields of type Set. When I retrieve the entity from the database the set is always empty even though the associations are correct in the database.

```
@Valid
@NotNull
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Location> locations;
```

I have tried enabling eager fetching to force hibernate to load the assocations when it retrives the entity but it's always empty. The other fields with non-collection types are populated correctly.

I have never seen this before with hibernate, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% but 99% sure that you need to add `cascade` to your `@OneToMany` - the default cascade is no cascade at all, meaning that if you persist your entity, the `Location` collection will not be persisted..

Try this:

```
@Valid
@NotNull
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Location> locations;
```

In other words your issue is not the collection not being fetched, but that it is not being persisted in the first place (did you see anything in the Location and the join table?)

Edit - I now see that you wrote the associations are correct, so do you persist your Location objects separately?

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the mappedBy attribute.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="fieldname")
```

Where fieldname should be the name of the referencing field in Location entity